# Using a child/sibling component with empty dom tree (<></>) to fetch data? Yay or Nay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So far the only example I've seen was a parent data wrapper that is fetching data and passing it to the child. I'm using Redux and planning to distribute data through 'connect'. Is it a bad code to create a react stateless component just for pure fetching?

Example:

```
const jsx = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App/> 
    <FetchingData >
  </Provider>

);
```

```
export const FetchingData = props => {
useEffect(()=>Listening to database and saving to Redux store...);

return <>
};
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  ...
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  ...
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(FetchingData);
```

Pros: easy to plug in, no need to to implement memo || shouldComponentUpdate since no children.

Cons: ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nay. Reason one: would someone reading either of the code fragments reasonably understand and identify an usual workflow? Even if someone is you after 1 month? Reason two: if you write something that violates reason one, there is 99% chance (and it is the case here) that you are using a peculiar workflow allowance that may change in the future, because the framework was NOT designed and will NOT be developed with this workflow in mind.

So, to recap, NAY, because of unreadable, unmaintainable code.